# Populating a Combobox through WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, combobox

I'm getting the Error, "Cannot Implicity convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumberable' to 'string'. An explicit conversions exists)"

I have tried using Convert.ToString() and .ToString however when this happens the ComboBox doesn't populate. 
I am able to directly populate with a SQLConnection however my main objective is to make it through the WCF Service.
What am I missing?

C#:

```
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindComboBox(cbxUsername);
    }

    public void BindComboBox(ComboBox Username)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        ServiceReference1.getUser GetUsername = new ServiceReference1.getUser();

        GetUsername.Username = cbxUsername.ItemsSource;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be other way,

```
 cbxUsername.ItemsSource = GetUsername.Username;
```